# Python - Skipping websocket callback "queue"

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-multithreading

I have the following:

```
def process(msg):
    print(msg)

    for i in range(10):         # This is in place of the
        print(i, end=' ')       # actual task, which takes
        time.sleep(1)           # around 10 seconds to run

ws = websocket()
ws.start_socket_abc(callback=process)
```

The websocket pushes info every second and makes a call to `process` each time.

Say the websocket is returning `"one"` for this second, `"two"` for the next second, `"three"` for the second after, and so on. Running the above code, the ouput would be:

```
one
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   <- this line takes 10 seconds to finish
two
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   <- this line takes 10 seconds to finish
...
```

It's clear that `process("two")` gets queued somewhere and is waited to be called after `process("one")` finishes. By the time the program prints out `two`, the real-time message should be `twelve`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to completely skip the "queue". I want it to take the message, do the task, skip all the calls in between (this is important, I actually need to skip them), take the next real-time message and do the task. In short, I want it to print out whatever real-time message is at the moment `process("one")` finishes. i.e.

```
one
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9   <- this line takes 10 seconds to finish
twelve
...
```

This is what I have in mind.

```
message = ''
def process(msg):
    message = msg

ws = websocket()
ws.start_socket_abc(callback=process)

def task(msg=message):
    print(msg)

    for i in range(10):         # This is in place of the
        print(i, end=' ')       # actual task, which takes
        time.sleep(1)           # around 10 seconds to run

start_thread(target=task)
```

This performs the task with the `message` variable, which changes in real-time with the messages received from the websocket so after `task("one")` finishes, `message` is at `"twelve"` and `task("twelve")` will be called, skipping all the messages in between.

I strongly doubt that this is the proper way of doing it. Someone please enlighten me, thanks in advance!